# Como sumar los datos de varias columnas de una consulta en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que registra las operaciones de los montos pagados, por ejemplo:

| CodPago | NumeroDoc | TipoDoc | Efectivo | Tarjeta | Cheques |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020 | Factura | 100 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 2020 | Factura | 0 | 150 | 0 |
| 03 | 2020 | Factura | 0 | 0 | 30 |
| 02 | 600 | Nota libre | 0 | 2000 | 0 |

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer un `select` en una sola fila por ejemplo de la transaccion con el NumeroDoc 2020 para que me la muestre asi

| NumeroDoc | TipoDoc | Efectivo | Tarjeta | Cheques |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Factura | 100 | 150 | 30 |

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! intentaste algo????

Comment: Intenta con `SELECT NumeroDoc, TipoDoc, Efectivo, Tarjeta, Cheques FROM el_nombre_de_tu_tabla WHERE NumeroDoc = 2020`

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?¿Conoces las funciones de agregación ?

Comment: Como acota @LuisCazares el caso de la pregunta es el básico uso de la funcón de agregación `SUM(...)` y la clausula de agrupación `GROUP BY` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 . Extender una explicación en un comentario no es procedente por lo que referencio un enlace